# What does `type` means in the following JavaScript snippet?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am (totally) newbie in JavaScript (or to be exact, in ES6), and using [this article](https://github.com/verekia/js-stack-from-scratch/blob/master/tutorial/05-redux-immutable-fetch.md#readme) to guide me. What I want to ask is the second line. What does `type` means in that import statement? Is `type` a keyword in JavaScript? Because if understand it correctly, I know that the line: `import type { fromJS } from 'immutable'`, is meant to import `fromJS` function from package `immutable` (I come from Python background).

I also see that in the line `action: {type: string, payload: any }) => {`, there is a `type` parameter. But I guess that is just coincidence, right?

```
import Immutable from 'immutable'
import type { fromJS } from 'immutable'

import { SAY_HELLO } from '../action/hello'

const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({
  message: 'Initial message',
})

const helloReducer = (state: fromJS = initialState, action: {type: string, payload: any }) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case SAY_HELLO:
      return state.set('message', action.payload)
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default helloReducer
```

dd

Comment: The paragraph below the code snippet in the article explains what `import type` is for.

Comment: Aaaargh, got it! That's why I am confuse in my code, as I don't rename fromJS. If you move your reply to the answer section, I will accept it as the answer.

Comment: Altough, @4castle, one question though. `fromJS` is function, right? Does that means `type` will return a function as the result of `import type {fromJS}` ? Or, is the type returning the variable type of `fromJS`?

Comment: @swdev: it "imports" the *type definiton* of `fromJS`. It's only used by flow for static analysis, it doesn't exist at runtime at all.

Comment: Okay, I see now. Kinda forgot, that Flow is an annotation library. I understand why it will get rid off eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the article you refer to is using the flow type library you can read more about it here: https://flow.org/

Comment: Okay, I see. Looking at this: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/modules/#importing-and-exporting-types-a-classtoc-idtoc-importing-and-exporting-types-hreftoc-importing-and-exporting-typesa I see the uses of `import type`.  And with this https://flow.org/en/docs/types/, I understand that it will import the data type of the variable, or function result. Cmiiw